# CSV matching values python

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file with fields

```
joburl, jobtitle,totalviews
```

I am trying to retrieve values for all `jobtitle`s separately. So far, I read all the `jobtitle`s of all `joburl`s and place unique `jobtitle`s in a separate text file. Now I want to read all of the text file, match the `jobtitle` in the text file with the `jobtitle` in the csv file and return `joburl` and view values for the particular `jobtitle`. 
The code is:

```
with open('Pagepath_detail.csv', 'rt') as f:
 with open('individual_jobtitle.txt') as title:
  for t in title:
      job = [row for row in csv.reader(f) if row[1] == t]
      print job
```

where `pagepath_detail` is the csv file I'm trying to extract the values from.
The code returns an empty array. But at the same time, if I try the direct approach such as:

```
with open('Pagepath_detail.csv', 'rt') as f:
 job = [row for row in csv.reader(f) if row[1] == 'job1']
 print job
```

The above code works perfectly.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at your code closely, there's a small issue with the looping you have.

You have interchanged the placement of the loops to be specific. Try the code below and it should work well for you.

```
with open('out.txt','r') as title:
    for t in title:
        with open('data.csv','r') as iFile:
            job = [row for row in csv.reader(iFile) if row[1].lstrip().rstrip() == t.lstrip().rstrip()]
            print job
```

Answer (score 1):

`for t in title` is iterating through the lines of the file, but also returns a newline character (`\n`) at the end of each line. Assuming that the file was created by using `print` for each jobtitle, what you may need to do is trim off the newlines returned as part of each `t`:

```
with open('Pagepath_detail.csv', 'rt') as f:
 with open('individual_jobtitle.txt') as title:
  for t in title:
   t = t.rstrip() # this line will convert 'job1\n' to 'job1'
   job = [row for row in csv.reader(f) if row[1] == t]
   print job
```

Note that the last line will sometimes be blank as well, but that only matters if one of more of your names are blank, too. Additionally, if there is no blank final line, then the last (nonblank) line will not usually have a newline at the end. That's OK because `rstrip` will just quietly return the line intact.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion it worked but it only returned values for job1 but returned empty for the rest.

Comment: Can you show an example of the contents of `individual_jobtitle.txt`? Is it just a newline separated list as described in this answer, or does it have other formatting applied?